# Authenticated Cloud Functions: Insufficient permission to access Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am setting up authenticated Cloud Functions for a function-function call as per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function). In my use case, the calling function is CF1 while the receiving function is CF2

I have set up and assign a service account (`my-func-invoker@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) for CF1, and setup/assign the Cloud Functions Invoker role for CF2 to the said `my-func-invoker@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account. All is good, CF1 can call CF2 with no problem.

However in CF1, there are 2 workflows:

1. Invoke CF2
2. Read/Write to Firestore

After assigning the service account to CF1, CF1 lost permission to read/write Firestore (my firestore currently grants all read write access) and throws the `7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably just need to give service account #1 the correct role to access firestore [0]. i would check what roles are currently granted to the SA and see if it's missing what is required.

[0] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#roles

Comment: Thanks! I added `roles/datastore.owner` to the SA and all is good.